# Necessary and sufficient conditions for $\Delta u = f$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $u(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In Sverak's course notes on PDEs, he mentions that, to prove the equation
$$\Delta u = f \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^2$$ 
$$ u(x) \rightarrow 0 \text{ as } |x| \rightarrow \infty$$
is solvable for smooth and compactly supported $f$, the necessary and sufficient condition is to show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f = 0$. I'm a bit lost on the steps of this proof, and I would like some clarification from the outline he gives.

The outline for the proof Sverak gives is as follows:

a) First show that the solution to the problem is a unique class of functions with sub-linear growth by the Liouville Theorem.

b) Show that the potential $u= G* f$ with kernel $G(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \log |x|$ is such a solution.

For part a, I think that first you need to adjust the function u so that it is harmonic. Considering $v$ so that $\Delta v = \Delta u - f$ should do the trick, but I am unsure of how this implies sub-linear growth for a certain class of functions. Still, by the Liouville we would get that $u \equiv 0$, which should give some sort of uniqueness.

For part b, I assume that I should just use the differentiable property of convolutions to show that the Laplacian of $u$ is $f$, and the fact that $f$ is compactly supported to show that $u(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$. I still need to work out these calculations, and will post once I have verified this.

I would also like someone to explain exactly why this implies the necessary and sufficient conditions. While seeing the sufficiency does not seem too bad (from the uniqueness of the solutions), I am assuming that the necessary part comes from the calculations in part b.

Comment: Yes for part b you get $\Delta u = G*\Delta f$

Comment: For (a), consider two solutions $\Delta u_1 = f$ and $\Delta u_2 = f$, and then consider $v = u_1 - u_2$.